# Reload Ember-Data from outside

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I am using Ember with Ember Data and the LocalStorage Adapter and I'm looking for a way to force ember to reload the data from the localstorage and update the UI accordingly.

However, I have no idea how to manually force a reload from outside of Ember. Basically I am looking for something like this:

```
function reloadAssets() {
  App.ApplicationAdapter.init(); // Cannot be called
}
```

My initial idea was to just call the init() method of the LS Application Adapter, but this is not possible.

Comment: Can you explain your workflow/lifecycle of a record?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to reconsider your application architecture if you can. But without knowing more, check out [Ember.Instrumentation](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Instrumentation.html). Not sure if this is the best way, but maybe it can help you.

You can use this to send send signals/events from outside of Ember into Ember.

```
// use jQuery to setup a click handler outside of Ember that will send
// Ember an an 'html.click' event that we defined
$('html').click(function(evt) {
  Ember.Instrumentation.instrument('html.click', evt);
});
```

Inside of Ember, you can define what happens when that event is detected:

```
// maybe in a route
Ember.Instrumentation.subscribe('html.click', {
  before: function(name, timestamp, payload) {
    this.send('handleHtmlClick', payload);
  },
  after: function(){}
});
```

I think you could do this to force an Ember route transition to have the records reloaded from the LSA.